# How to use external URL as path (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to create routes within an app that I am working on like the following example:

http://www.example.com/entrepreneur.com/article/251468

My hope is to basically load an external page into an iframe by adding our domain to the URL. It needs to be without storing the external url in a database because I need every website accessable in this way. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need a route with a wildcard like this:

```
get 'url/*args', to: 'your_controller#your_action'
```

- See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments
- I would suggest you namespace the route under some keyword to catch this wildcard route explicitly (hence `url` in the above).
- You may need to tweak the route to allow periods to prevent them from becoming the `format`. I forget if that's true for these or not.

Comment: This is the answer you need